# react-hook-form input handler taking too long

Tags: reactjs, forms, performance, react-hook-form

I had a big performance issue using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) in [context mode](https://react-hook-form.com/api#useFormContext). Input events like `onblur`, `onchange` and `onfocus` were taking more than 1 second to respond.

Comment: It's honorable that you want to share the solution to a problem that others may encounter. I would be nice if you could add the solution as an answer to your own question instead of including it in the question itself. This way it will be shown as having an answer rather than being unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The problem root was having a Google Chrome/Edge extension enabled called [React-Sight](https://www.reactsight.com/). When the add-on finally crashed due to memory issues, the form performance was improved so much in a point to be finally usable again.